# Reversing bootstrap row in forEach (in .php file) statement with only css

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4, sass

I am trying to reverse row in forEach statement. for example, in first row, content's div (title, text) would be on the left side and image on the right side and in a second row reverse, image on left side and content on right  but I cant find solution, here is my code:

```css
.bloges {
    &__row:nth-child(odd) {
        .toko {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    }
    &__row:nth-child(even) {
        .toko {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row-reverse;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="container p-2 bloges">
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($meta_blogs_top_step_0 as $data) {
?>      
        <div class="row bloges__row">
            <div class="toko">
<?php
                if(file_exists(DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/modules/meta_blogs_top/uploads/'.$data['id'].'.jpg')) {
?>  
                    <div class="col-md-6 p-2">
                        <img src="/modules/meta_blogs_top/uploads/<?= $data['id']?>.jpg">
                    </div>
<?php
                }
?>
                <div class="col-md-6 bloges__content">
                    <div class="p-2 mt-5 mb-4">
                        <h3 class="line_1">
                            <?= $data['title_'.LANG] ?>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 mb-4">
                        <div class="line_7">
                            <?= $data['text_'.LANG] ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-2 mb-lg-4 mb-sm-3 mb-2">
                        <a href="<?= '/'.LANG.'/'.$data['alias_'.LANG] ?>">
                            <div class="p-2 d-inline-block text-center bloges__more_button bloges__more_button--hover">
                                <?= bsw :: get('more') ?>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
        if($i < 2 ) {
?>
            <div class="py-2 text-center">
                <img src="/images/under_title_graphics.svg" class="w-auto mx-auto">
            </div>
<?php
        $i++;
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php  
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

foreach ($colors as $key => $value) {
  if($key == reset($colors))
  {
    //first
  }
  else
  {
    //second,third....
  }
  
}
?>
```